# Определение позиции выбранного элемента в HorizontalScrollView

Tags: java, android, horizontalscrollview

Я делаю свою галерею. Для этого решил использовать `HorizontalScrollView`. Добавить картинки не составило особого труда, но у `HorizontalScrollView` отсутствует слушатель нажатия на элемент, который был добавлен в `HorizontalScrollView` и находится в фокусе(выведен на экран) в данный момент. А мне необходимо выполнить действия, например удалить картинку, которая находится сейчас (видна) в `HorizontalScrollView`.

Как можно определить позицию видимой картинки?

Comment: Лучше не придумывать новые костыли с HorizontalScrollView, а сделать правильно - при помощи ViewPager. У него есть и слушатель, и позицию спросить можно.

Comment: Можно немного упароться и сделать через адаптер, а не HorizontalListView, если такой вариант интересен, то могу сказать, что сделать, но насколько я знаю, есть слушатель **OnItemSelectedListener()** Этот слушатель вы ципляете к своей HorizontalScrollBView

Comment: Просто тут ещё вопрос в том какой HorizontalScrollView вы используете, насколько мне известно такого стандартного решения от Google, обычно это сторонние библиотеки, возможно у них слушатель называется по другому, стоит почитать про либу, если есть возможность посмотреть код въюхи, то если HorizontalScrollView наследуется от дефолтного ListView, то в любом случае к нему можно подципить слушатель, о котором я писал выше

Comment: BORSHEVIK, как  ListView можно переделать в горизонтальный список? Если можно, то меня это бы устроило

Comment: @selya Вас какая минимальная версия API устроит?

Comment: @selya Вот нормальная библиотека для вашего решения https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView, но даже сам автор написал, что данное решение deprecated и поэтому лучше делать через RecyclerView. Поэтому решение от mrBatonec самое адекватное. Вот вам пример на русском для реализации RecyclerView http://www.fandroid.info/primer-ispolzovaniya-cardview-i-recyclerview-v-android/ сам юзал и всем рекомендую. Просто внестите изменения в этот код, как предложил  человек ниже и будет крутиться по горизонтали

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужен горизонтально прокручивающийся список, то используйте [RecycleView](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) с горизонтальным [LinearLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html)

`LinearLayoutManager manager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(.....);
rv.setLayoutManager(manager);`

Comment: Ваш вариант самый адекватный, но боюсь автор может не разобраться

Comment: @BORSHEVIK а может еще и подскажите как стороннюю библиотеку подключить в eclipse? А то вроде получилось, но при инициализации контента setContentView(R.layout.viewing); выдается ошибка Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView